# Updating foreign key field in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a form that displays a drop down for a foreignkey field. The form saves the users selection, however I want the view to update the database entry rather than inserting a new one. Whats the best way to go about this?

Current function:

```
def formset_valid(self, formset):
    self.object = formset.save()
    self.object.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

I have tried something like this:

```
d = RevisionDefaultType.objects.get(id=1)
n = RevisionSettings.objects.get(self.object)
d.defaultrevisiontype = n
d.save()
```

But it throws an error that the data being updated is not an instance.

Comment: Can you show your models? I also don't understand your code: why are you referring to a formset when you obviously have a form (otherwise `self.object.save()` would be invalid); and `RevisionSettings.objects.get(self.object)` is not valid unless RevisionSettings.objects is a dictionary, which it shouldn't be.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was orignally using an inlineformset to display 2 forms but it didnt work so when i found the solution the names just stayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to tweak the update example from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#saving-foreignkey-and-manytomanyfield-fields. This seems to be working as desired.

```
    def formset_valid(self, formset):

        self.object = formset.save(commit=False)
        revdefault = RevisionDefaultType.objects.get(pk=1)
        revget = RevisionSettings.objects.get(global_revision_type=self.object)
        revdefault.defaultrevisiontype = revget
        revdefault.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You must add `force_update=True` to your `save()` function.

For more info  about **How Django knows to UPDATE vs. INSERT** see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert) link in django's documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the post. Ive updated my code to:
 
self.object = formset.save(commit=False)
d = RevisionDefaultType.objects.get(id=1)
d.defaultrevisiontype = self.object
d.save(force_update=True)

Still getting: Cannot assign "<RevisionDefaultType: D>": "RevisionDefaultType.defaultrevisiontype" must be a "RevisionSettings" instance.